# number_format() causes error "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am using number_format to round floats to only 2 decimal digits. The problem is that some of my inputs don't have more than 2 decimals digits to begin with. So the code:

```
number_format($value, 2)
```

Instead of peacefully adding 0 in case it doesn't have enough decimal digits, it raises errors inside Apache log and that's not desirable.

So `number_format(2.1, 2)` or `number_format(0, 2)` will raise error in Apache log.

> [Thu Jun 30 17:18:04 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/tahoang/Desktop/Projects/weatherData/weatherData.php on line 41

How to fix this?

Comment: @zerkms: `PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered`

Comment: Have you tried `number_format(0.0, 2)`?

Comment: We won't be able to help you if don't tell us what error you're having.

Comment: @eyazici: Yes, the same error raised.

Comment: @yes123: My LAMP stack is up to date sir.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try type casting first parameter of [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to float:

```
$format = number_format((float)0, 2);
```

or

```
$format = number_format(floatval(0), 2);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to replace decimal point and after that cast to float.

```
var_dump((float)number_format((float)str_replace(",", ".", "20,5"), 2, ".", ""));
result: float(20.5);
```

Without replacing:

```
var_dump((float)number_format(floatval("20,5"), 2, ".", ""));
result: float(20);
var_dump((float)number_format((float) "20,5", 2, ".", ""));
result: float(20);
```

Answer (score 3):

When doing calculations, use

`number_format($value, 2, ".", "")`

And if you would like to display numbers with .00 at the end (like "50.50" not "50.5") then you would use

`numer_format($value, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```
str_replace(array(".", ","), array(",", "."), $value)
```

Maybe it'll help someone out.

Answer (score 1):

Function is recognizing it as a string.

Convert to number by adding zero:

```
number_format($NUMBER+0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when passing `"0..6"` in `number_format()` function.

I just replaced `..` to `.` in price column of the table.

Comment: Please don't put everything into code blocks.

Comment: You're basically saying that you fixed a typo in your data to solve the problem. How is this an answer?

Comment: Well, this actually would have been a better answer if you had just stated "Check that your argument is well formatted." Right now, this only mentions one very specific error that others are unlikely to have.

Answer (score -1):

I struggle a lot with this error and it was because a return type `float` like this:

```php
protected function example(): float {
   ...
   return number_format($number, 2);
}
```

The error was not the `$number` but the conversion of string with "." and "," in float when returning the string generated by `number_format`.