# A non well formed numeric value encountered when converting integer to thousand separator

Tags: php, numeric

I have a PHP code to retrieve a value from a website. I got the output but also a notice:
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in line 19.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$grep = new DoMDocument();
@$grep->loadHTMLFile("https://www.postme.com.my/men-1.html");

$finder = new DomXPath($grep);
$class = "amount";

$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]");

$i = 0;
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($i<1) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    $replace = str_replace("Items 1-12 of", "",$span->item(0)->nodeValue);
    echo number_format($replace, 0 , '.' , ',' ) . '<br/>';
  }
   $i++;
  }
?>
```

How do I correct it so the notice will not come out when I assigned a number format to it.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the content of `$replace` at every iteration to see if, at some point, it's not a number ?

Comment: The output is integer..I already replaces all the characters with blank.

Comment: Got it...I just put $convert =  (int)$replace;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place an at symbol in front of the command to ignore all notices and such. It's bad form usually, but it should work.

```
echo @number_format($replace, 0 , '.' , ',' ) . '<br/>';
```

Edit: @ was in the wrong place.

Also, as was suggested, you could also check to be sure that the value is numeric:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

```
if(is_numeric($replace){
    echo number_format($replace, 0 , '.' , ',' ) . '<br/>';
}
```

Edit Edit: You could also try typecasting the variable as mentioned here:

[number_format() causes errors in Apache log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542403/number-format-causes-errors-in-apache-log)

Comment: No please, don't suggest people to use that `@` operator. It's never a good idea to hide errors, warnings and notices ... It's **way** better to know what is the problem, and then to handle it properly.

Comment: @ClémentMalet I agree with you, which I why I mentioned that it's bad form. I expanded my answer to include is_numeric to help avoid the error suppression.