# Using number_format method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am fairly new in Laravel and Blade templating.
Can anyone help show me how to do this?

**I have a view like this:**

```
@foreach ($Expenses as $Expense)
    <tr>
        <td>{{{ $Expense->type }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ $Expense->narration }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ $Expense->price }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ $Expense->quantity }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ $Expense->amount }}}</td>                                                            
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I want the `$Expense->price` and`$Expense->amount` to be formatted.
I tried using it on the `$Expense->amount` as `number_format($Expense->amount)` but it didn't work.

Comment: `<td><?php echo number_format($Expense->amount); ?></td>` would be one option; but `<td>{{ number_format($Expense->amount,2) }}</td>` should work

Comment: I tried both, none works

Comment: So what do you actually see in the markup?

Comment: I found the reason why it doesn't work, I did `var_dump` and found out my database column for the amount, price and quantity are all string. I have refreshed my migrations and made the columns float and now it works fine. Thank you

Comment: @HayatuMohammedAbubakar You can pass a string like `'1.23'` to `number_format` and it'll work. Were you storing dollar signs as part of the string, perhaps, i.e. `'$1.23'`?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This should work :

```
<td>{{ number_format($Expense->price, 2) }}</td>
```

Comment: May also need to look at typecasting it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542403/number-format-causes-error-a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered to make it work properly

Comment: More details for PHP's `number_format()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Eloquent, in your model put:

```
public function getPriceAttribute($price)
{
    return $this->attributes['price'] = sprintf('U$ %s', number_format($price, 2));
}
```

Where get**Price**Attribute is your field on database. get**Something**Attribute.

Comment: Personally, using this answer I would move the `sprintf` into a reusable component like `App\Localization\Currency::format($price)` in the event  it needs to be flexible without too much abstraction.  But either way this is a spot on answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is a much better OOP implementation. The accepted answer is fine, but if anything changes across the app for formatting it's a nightmare to make adjustments.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Eloquent the best solution is:

```
public function getFormattedPriceAttribute()
{
    return number_format($this->attributes['price'], 2);
}
```

So now you must append formattedPrice in your model and you can use both, price (at its original state) and formattedPrice.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way of doing it, add in app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

...

public function boot()
{
    // add Str::currency macro
    Str::macro('currency', function ($price)
    {
        return number_format($price, 2, '.', '\'');
    });
}
```

Then use Str::currency() in the blade templates or directly in the Expense model.

```
@foreach ($Expenses as $Expense)
    <tr>
        <td>{{{ $Expense->type }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ $Expense->narration }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ Str::currency($Expense->price) }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ $Expense->quantity }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ Str::currency($Expense->amount) }}}</td>                                                            
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, use this code:

Example:

```
$number = 1234.56;
$format_number = number_format($number);
```

See the link for more information about number_format(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php