# How to obtain a float from a laravel table?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I need to obtain the float number from the table so that I can use it to carry out accurate calculations. For example:

```
mytable

ID|accessone|accesstwo
1 |  3.2    |  4.1

$mynumber = DB::table('mytable')

               ->where('id', 1)->first();
```

I would like to be able to do

```
$mycalculation = ($mynumber->accessone + $mynumber->accesstwo);

and so that in my view I can do
```

View

```
{{$mycalculation}}
```

but unfortunately I get 7 and not 7.3

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: in my view I do `{{$mycalculation}}` and get 7 and not 7.3

Comment: Not knowing laravel but Googling looks like some template engine in the mix too, Eloquent?  See an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651808/using-number-format-method-in-laravel

Comment: the `number_format` method does not work unfortunately

Comment: If you call `dd($myNumber)` what is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have a procteced function within your model that recognises that the fillable field is set as a float

```
MytableModel

protected $casts = [
    'id'        => 'integer',
    'accessone' => 'float',
    'accesstwo' => 'float',
    ];
```

Example usage:

```
$mycalculation = numberformat($mynumber->accessone, 1) +
                 number_format($mynumber->accesstwo, 1);
```