# PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, page-load-time

I write a function like this:-

```
function loadTime() {
    $load = microtime();
    return number_format($load,2);
}
```

and then call it with a piece of HTML code:

```
Page generated in <?php echo loadTime() ?> seconds.
```

I think you can guess what i wanna do! i wanna display my page load time with this PHP function, i have to say that this function works but when i open `error_log` it shows this error:

> PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   /home/coffeesc/public_html/index.php on line 12

as I searched, I think something is wrong with time or even date! no idea but I wonder if you can suggest me a way for displaying page load time with php (somehow in `ms`)

Comment: `<?php

$time = microtime();

$time = explode(' ', $time);

$time = $time[1] + $time[0];

$finish = $time;

$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);

echo 'Page generated in '.$total_time.' seconds.';

?>`

Comment: `1485701614.7234 seconds` whats this :| ? @Anant

Comment: that is page load time

Comment: i know dude ;) would you please explain me whats the problem with that function i write and that error_log content ? how can i solve it ? @Anant

Comment: The same problem has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542403/number-format-causes-errors-in-apache-log), basically you need to typecast like `number_format((float)$load, 2);`

Answer (score 8):

If you use `microtime()` and set the `get_as_float` parameter you get a simple floating point number that is just what you need for this kind of calculation

```
$page_start = microtime(1);

// all page code
sleep(2);

echo 'Page generated in ' . (microtime(1) - $page_start) . ' seconds';
```

The result being something like this

```
Page generated in 2.0001142024994 seconds
```